# Facing Linkage error while using Firedac in Delphi 12.0

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Delphi 12 for developing Android mobile application. I have used Firedac databasse for storing the data by SQLLite and also implemented the FDSSecurity component for data encryption. And I can able to run the android application using Delphi 11 but got the error while running the application:

> Project  raised exception class EFDException with message
> '[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite][sqlite3]-303. Capability is not supported'.

And I have used the following code to fix this:

```
initialization
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink := TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.Create(nil);
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.EngineLinkage  := slFDEStatic; // compatibility Delphi >=12

finalization
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.Free;
```

But, now I'm getting the error message -

> `Project <app> raised exception class EFDException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite]-1606. SQLite library linkage [FDEStatic] is not found. Hint: If static linkage is requested and supported, include [FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper.Stat] into your project'.`

I have searched several option to fix the issue but not got the solution.